FHIR Bundle batch validation
I want to validate a FHIR Bundle against a remote FHIR server using a single request. The incoming bundle can contain both valid or invalid resources. The response bundle should contain validation results for each incoming bundle entry. Is this supported by the standard?

I would say yes. The standard allows for a batch type Bundle to contain operation calls, see http://hl7.org/fhir/http.html#transaction. In your case, per entry you could specify that you want $validate to be executed, and can also specify parameters for that (like the profile to validate against) as long as they're of a primitive type.
That said, it will depend on what is invalid in the resources if this will actually work. A server may run into parse errors while parsing the whole Bundle, and might reject it based on that before it gets to the individual validations. And there are servers that might not support batch interactions at all.
